# Windows 10, disable auto-configuring DNS servers via IPv6 connection

Tags: networking, windows-10, dns, ipv6

Windows 10 has this dialog for IPv6:

[image: WIndows IPv6 COnfig dialog]

I do not want to autoconfigure DNS servers via IPv6 (The DNS servers obtained via IPv4 are sufficient, and the DNS servers the router from my ISP sends via DHCPv6 are semi broken).

However just selecting "Use the following DNS server addresses" and leaving them blank does not work. After clicking Ok and entering the same dialog, the setting has just jumped back to "Obtain DNS server addresses automatically"

Is there anyway I can disable obtaining DNS addresses via IPv6, but still auto-configure an IPv6 address ?

Comment: have you tried entering the IPv6 address(es) for the DNS server(s)? I believe that's what that input box is looking for.

Comment: @mael' I do have any IPv6 DNS servers that I can or want to enter there.  I do not want to use any IPv6 DNS servers.

Comment: From my limited understanding: a device with an IPv6 address will attempt to send packets via IPv6 and the router's IPv6 address; if it cannot resolve to an IPv6 address (via a DNS configured with IPv6) it won't use it. It sounds like you're better off just disabling it entirely if you don't want to set an IPv6 address on your DNS - most publicly used DNS include an IPv6 path.

Comment: @mael' DNS servers on IPv4 are perfectly capable of serving AAAA records. There is no correspondence there. OP: Just put in Google's DNS servers or whatever other DNS and have done with it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Are you saying there is no way to get DNS servers dynamically ONLY from the IPv4 connection ? The choice I have is to either a) disable IPv6 alltogether or b) hardcode a DNS server ?

Comment: @MichaelHampton yes but I was under the impression that those DNS servers had to be specifically configured to serve those IPv6 addresses - or is that not correct? and nos, have you tried putting your DNS's IPv4 addresses in the server spots?

Comment: @mael' Michael is correct, IPv4 DNS servers responds just fine with AAAA records. No, you can not place IPv4 addresses in there, it expects IPv6 addresses for the DNS server addresses. My question is still if I can just disable the IPv6 connection setting any DNS servers at all. I'd be surprised if there's no netsh command that can disable it.

Comment: Why do you not want to put in your own DNS servers, then? It sounds like you're in a situation where you really need to override your ISP's choices.

Comment: @MichaelHampton My question is not about how I can get out of my current situation, it is about whether you can disable auto-configuring DNS servers via IPv6 connection. I had hoped that question had a positive answer. Personally I would prefer to use just the DNS servers that are autoconfigured via the IPv4 connection so I don't have to manage this manually or otherwise deploy a rather silly workaround.

Comment: Well, the workaround you've proposed is also rather silly,  as the actual problem is your ISP's broken DNS servers. The difference is that the workaround you've proposed doesn't appear to be possible.

Answer (score 4):

Seems to me that filling the Preferred DNS Server field with something is required.  I suggest:

Preferred DNS Server - **::1**,
Alternate DNS Server - ***blank***

DNSv6 will fail immediately and auto fallback to DNSv4.

Comment: While this works for general use, it make makes `nslookup` fail as it will try to only use the `::1` address.

Answer (score 0):

There are public DNS servers on the internet (for both IPv4 and IPv6), you are free to use those if ISP provided one's are broken

1. Google: 2001:4860:4860::8888 and 2001:4860:4860::8844 (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 for IPv4, see https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using)
2. OpenDNS: 2620:0:ccc::2 and 2620:0:ccd::2 (208.67.222.222 and 208.67.220.220 for IPv4)
3. Cloudflare and Quad9 do also operate public DNS servers and you can use those if you choose so.

Just put those adressed into "Preferred DNS Server" and "Alternate DNS Server" fields. This might be a solution, IDK whatever exactly you are trying to achieve.